# Seeking pointers to resolve "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jwt')" issue

Tags: next.js, strapi, next-auth

I am having an issue with my auth flow, and hoping someone with keen eye might help me resolve the issue. The error I am getting is `[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]  https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jwt')`, and have since reviewed the code multiple times to see what might have gone wrong. Here are the steps I took, and how you might be able to reproduce the error:

1. Set up and configured `[...nextauth].js file` as shown below
2. Updated Providers with credentials needed.

Upon trying to login to test, I got the error messages as shown below.

`frontend/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import FacebookProvider from 'next-auth/providers/facebook';
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';

const options = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
    signOut: '/',
    error: '/auth/error', // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: '/auth/verify-request', // (used for check email message)
    newUser: '/firstpage', // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  database: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL,
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  callbacks: {
    session: async (session, user) => {
      session.jwt = user.jwt;
      session.id = user.id;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
    jwt: async (token, user, account) => {
      const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
      if (isSignIn) {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL}/auth/${account.provider}/callback?access_token=${account?.accessToken}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("DATTA",data);
        token.jwt = data.jwt;
        token.id = data.user.id;
      }
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },
  },
};

const Auth = (req, res) =>
  NextAuth(req, res, options);

export default Auth;
```

`Error below`

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jwt') {
  message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jwt')",
  stack: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jwt')\n" +
    '    at Object.session (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js:45:32)\n' +
    '    at Object.session (/Users/PATH-TO-FILES...)\n'

  name: 'TypeError'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace URI in jwt callback to:
`` const response = await fetch(      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/auth/${account.provider}/callback?access_token=${account?.access_token}`); ``

Here is my configuration for `[...nextauth].js`. **Note: I'm using `authOptions` instead `options` to be able to get a session on a server in `getServerSideProps`.**

````
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import axios from 'axios';

const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Email',
      type: 'credentials',

      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;

        try {
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/auth/local`,
            {
              identifier: email,
              password: password,
            }
          );
          const user = await data;

          if (user) {
            return user;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (err) {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],

  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.jwt = token.jwt;
      session.id = token.id;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      if (user) {
        if (account.provider !== 'credentials') {
          const response = await fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/auth/${account.provider}/callback?access_token=${account?.access_token}`
          );
          const data = await response.json();

          token.jwt = data.jwt;
          token.id = data.user.id;
        } else {
          token.jwt = user.jwt;
          token.id = user.user.id;
        }
      }

      return token;
    },
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },
};

const Auth = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, authOptions);

export default Auth;```
````